# Non-unicode printf's don't work

Tags: c++, windows, unicode, visual-studio-2015, console-application

I have enabled wide-string support in my C++ console application using:

```
_setmode(_fileno(stdin), _O_WTEXT);
_setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_WTEXT);
```

I can read and output unicode characters just fine now using `wprintf` (or `std::wcin`), but because of this, plain `printf` (and `std::cin`) calls won't work as they throw exceptions. Is there any way to bypass/correct this? Replacing them does not sound like a solution.

Comment: Use `_O_TEXT` and `_O_WTEXT` to switch back and forth between ANSI and UNICODE. `_setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_TEXT)` will set the output back to ANSI

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `wprintf` to output wide characters.

`printf` does not allow to write to a wide/unicode stream:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/wc7014hz.aspx

Comment: Correction: use `wprintf` to output _wide_ characters.

Comment: But the question is: how to output non-unicode characters using good ol' `printf`?

Comment: ^^^^ True, my bad.

Comment: From msdn: printf does not currently support output into a UNICODE stream. https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/wc7014hz.aspx

Comment: @Bigiansen Thanks! That's the answer; guess there is no way around this.